# Facebook Share Thumbnail

Tags: posts, facebook

From the past few weeks I am noticing that when I share my posts on facebook, the thumbnail is not coming, I am keeping a featured image for my posts, but when I share it on facebook it shares the link without thumbnail, I tried using several code which I found on google, but none of them works.

I am using twenty eleven theme with latest WP

Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add [Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) meta tags to your `<head>`.  See `og:image` below...

```
<meta property="og:title" content="35% of LinkedIn Users Check The Site Daily" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://therealtimereport.com/2011/08/05/35-of-linkedin-users-check-the-site-daily/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://therealtimereport.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/LinkedIn-Users-Are-Highly-Engaged.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="The Realtime Report" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Now the No.2 ranked social networking site - as of June 2011 - LinkedIn has a highly engaged, profession-focused audience, according to new research from Lab42.  Based on a survey of LinkedIn users in July 2011, the data reveals that 32% of users check the site several times a week, and more than a third - 35% - check the site daily." />
```

Comment: Hey thanks after your answer I searched for some plugin, and found a promising plugin
  `WP Facebook Open Graph protocol`
Thanks chris

Comment: Nijraj, Do you still use this plugin?